# Asymptotic behavior of integral involving Jacobi theta function

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, special-functions

Define a function
$$F_\lambda(\omega) = \int_0^1 \exp\left(-2\pi i \int_0^t \vartheta_3(-\pi t', \lambda)dt'\right) e^{2\pi i\omega t} dt,$$
where $\lambda\in(0,1)$ is fixed and $\omega\in \mathbb R$. Here, $\vartheta_3$ is the Jacobi theta function defined as $\vartheta_3(u,q) = 1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2} \cos(2nu)$.

**Question**: What is the asymptotic behavior of $F_\lambda(\omega)$ for either $\omega \to \infty$ and $\omega \to -\infty$?

Remark:

1. The stationary phase method shows that $F_\lambda(\omega) = O(1/\omega^n)$ for arbitrary $n\in \mathbb N$.
2. At $\lambda=1/2$, I numerically obtained $\log_{10}|F_{1/2}(\omega)|^2$ as a function of $\omega$:

[image]

$|F_{1/2}(\omega)|^2$ seems to decay exponentially, and non-symmetrically.

Comment: I’m a bit confused on the definition of the theta function. Should I interpret the $q$ in the sum as the nome, as then the argument shouldn’t be $\vartheta(u,q)$ but rather $\vartheta(u,\tau)$ with $\tau=\exp(\pi i \tau)$.

Comment: @AxelT Thanks for your comment. The question should be interpreted as it is written. The definition of $\vartheta_3$ comes from the Mathematica (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta.html). Although the definition in the link may be non-standard, please adhere to what is written there, since my computation is based on Mathematica.

Comment: I see. I’m a bit unsure on which definition is standard, I’ve only read a little of the function on Wikipedia. But good to have it clarified! If no one tries before me, I’ll see if I manage to look at it tomorrow. Guess it depends on how hard it is no expand the $\exp$ with the $\vartheta$ around 0, I think it should be simple after that (but I may be wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with defining the integral $I(x) = I_1(x) + iI_2(x)$ with

$$
I_1(x) = \int_0^1 \cos(g(t))\exp(2\pi ixt)dt, \quad I_2(x) = \int_0^1 \sin(g(t))\exp(2\pi ixt)dt, \quad x\to \infty
$$

which then gives that the integral of interest is $I(x)$ with $g(t) = -2\pi\int_0^t \vartheta_3(-\pi t',\lambda)dt'$. Note that for each integral, there are no stationary points, this means that only the points $a=0$ and $b=1$ will contribute to the answer.

Given an integral on the form $I(x) = \int_{a}^b q(t)\exp(ixp(t))dt$ with no stationary points, it's value is asymptotically

$$
I(x) \sim \frac{ie^{ixp(a)}q(a)}{xp'(a)} - \frac{ie^{ixp(b)}q(b)}{xp'(b)}, \quad x\rightarrow \infty
$$

So let's look at the theta function. We have

$$
\int_0^t \vartheta_3(-\pi t',\lambda)dt' = \int_0^t  \left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(2\pi nt') \right)dt = t+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^t \cos(2\pi nt')dt' = t +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{n^2} \frac{\sin(2\pi nt)}{\pi n}
$$

so

$$
g(t) = -2\pi t-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{n^2} \frac{\sin(2\pi nt)}{n}
$$

Clearly, $g(0)=0$ and $g(1) = -2\pi$. It is quite interesting to note that asymptotically, it is only the term $-2\pi t$ which contributes to the asymptotic expansion. I.e. if we plot the numerical solution where we truncate at different number of terms as a function of $x$, all will approach the same value for sufficiently large $x$.

For $I_1(x)$, let $p(t) = 2\pi t, q(t) = \cos(g(t))$. Note that $g(0) = 0  \Rightarrow q(0)=1$ and $g(1)=-2\pi\Rightarrow q(1) = 1$. Thus, one has

$$
I_1(x) \sim \frac{i}{2\pi x} \left(1 - e^{2\pi ix} \right)
$$

with (one may check that this is true for both $x\to\pm\infty$)

$$
\Re(I_1(x)) \sim \frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi x}, \quad \Im(I_1(x)) \sim \frac{1}{2\pi x} (1-\cos(2\pi x)), \quad x\to \pm \infty
$$

Now, we also look at $I_2(x)$, which is the same above except having $q(t)=\sin(g(t))$ instead. But at the endpoints, $q(0)=0$ and $q(1)=0$ in this case, so $I_2(x) \sim 0$ to leading order. Looking at this numerically, one sees that there are oscillations which decay faster than $O(x^{-1})$.

The asymptotics for $I(x)$ are seen below, compared to the numerical solution (here $\lambda = 0.5$).

[image]

Now, I'd like to add that I'm a bit unsure if I did things correctly. Clearly, the numerical integral I've plotted fits nicely, but I'm not certain if it's correctly implemented.o it would be nice to see if you can verify the results on your part as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your calculation seems correct. Actually I am interested in the case $x\in \mathbb Z$, where your asymptotic is zero at the leading order. I should have mentioned that in the question! At the special points $x\in \mathbb Z$, maybe the integrand decays exponentially.

Comment: Ah, that explains a bit. I got unsure as I didn’t notice any exponential decay. I guess I could calculate the second term as well, it is only a matter of partial integrations. I’m not sure it decays exponentially though.

Comment: But out of curiosity, how did you get the integral? I remember your question about the asymptotic of a hypergeometric function, is this something similar?

Comment: Yes, it is :) All the two questions are motivated from a physics problem, which is too long and off-topic at this site.